# Batch delete a folder from %LOCALAPPDATA%

Tags: javascript, powershell, batch-file, windows-7

I have a need of deleting a specific folder from all users local profiles in
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\`

I have created a short script to do this and I have to run it as Administrator because I run another program first.

```
call c:\test.exe

rd /s /q %LOCALAPPDATA%\test
```

The problem is that this will only delete the folder in the administrator's AppData and not in all others user's folders.

Is there any way to do it in batch, Powershell or eventually in VBS?

My operating system is Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```psh
Remove-Item 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\test' -Recurse -Force
```

In VBScript:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each sf In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users").SubFolders
  f = fso.BuildPath(sf.Path, "AppData\Local\test")
  If fso.FolderExists(f) Then fso.DeleteFolder f, True
Next
```

In batch:

```sh
for /d %d in (C:\users) do @if exists "%d\AppData\Local\test" rd /s /q "%d\AppData\Local\test"
```